# Visual studio 2015 Properties panel

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm reading a tutorial about `c# wpf` projects and at some point it tells me to put a tab control on my project and set its properties like this:

```
Grid.RowSpan="2" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="2" Width="408" Height="208" Grid.Row="1"
```

My novice problem is that I cannot find `Grid.RowSpan` property on properties panel in order to change it.

1. Are some properties available only from xaml editor?
2. Is there a way to find it on properties panel also?

Answer (score 1):

You tabcontrol goes inside the page's grid, so the Grid.RowSpan property is inherited from that.

Additionally, you may have defined some rows in your grid in a way similar to this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
```

So, basically, that should work. RowSpan is written with Capital "R" and "S" btw, could htat be it?

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not entirely sure, but some are definitely easier to use from XAML.
2. It is in the layout properties (see picture).

[Grid.Rowspan in VS Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R29s9.png)

Comment: You are absolutely right. It was my mistake . I had put the tab control over a canvas object , thats why i didn't find the property.